# AngularJS filter with multiple parameters

Tags: angularjs, filter

I want to be able to filter my table with many parameters passed in as an array. Therefore I can build up an array of filter params and pass them in. I don't want to explicitly state what columns to filter against as there could be many columns (some which will be shown and some not).

The HTML looks something like this;

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in infoData | filter:['param1','param2']">
    <td>{{item.data1}}</td>
    <td>{{item.data2}}</td>
    <td>{{item.data3}}</td>
    <td>{{item.data4}}</td>
</tr>
```

Is there away to filter a table against multiple parameters?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the quick and dirty way to accomplish what you need.

First create a custom filter in the controller something like this:

```
$scope.customFilter = function(param1, param2) {
   return function(item) {
      //return custom stuff here
   }
}
```

then in the html you do this

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in infoData | filter:customFilter(param1, param2)">
   <td>{{item.data1}}</td>
   <td>{{item.data2}}</td>
   <td>{{item.data3}}</td>
   <td>{{item.data4}}</td>
</tr>
```

this is an example with a custom filter

```
app.filter('customFilter', function (param1, param2) {
    return function (item) {
       //return custom stuff here
    };
});
```

and now in the html you do this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in infoData | customFilter(param1, param2)">
   <td>{{item.data1}}</td>
   <td>{{item.data2}}</td>
   <td>{{item.data3}}</td>
   <td>{{item.data4}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be added to a custom filter, instead of the controller?

Comment: This is the quick and dirty way, but you most certainly could build a custom filter, especially if the filter is complex. I updated the answer.